How would I seamlessly connect parts of the same object?
So I have a model I'm working on that primarily uses the 'skin modifier' to give it shape.


How would I go about seamlessly connecting the neck to the body? (they both are part of the same object btw)

This question is similar to: Removing internal geometry. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Then we can vote to re-open the question.
